# Microsoft Teams: Why mobile devices can't render a card with broken image link

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

We are working with the [Adaptive Card Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to make cards.
Before adding new cards we create them in the Adaptive card designer and if everything works fine we copy Card Payload to work with.

I don't know if this expected but we had an issue i will describe below.

When you are adding an image to your Card you can see how will it be rendered in the card. If the image url is broken this reflects straight away on the card preview.

I've added a space between h and t in the protocol "https" of the image url. You can see that the image cannot be rendered in the preview. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Ok this works as intended. But, once we move that space symbol before the protocol we see this:

[image]

If we send this card to teams this card can be rendered on the desktop without any image:

[image]

But on the mobile devices (Android/IOS) this card **can't be rendered at all**:

[image]

Looks like we can't trust Adaptive Card Designer anymore, when we are copy/pasting things.

Is this a bug, or?

Comment: I have seen the same issue, I will confirm internally.

Comment: We have raised a bug, internal team is looking into it. I will update you once it is fixed.

Comment: @Oleksa - There shouldn't be any space at the beginning of URL otherwise it will throw error. This behavior is by design.